# Add title element to SVG rect through js/javascript or jquery?

Tags: svg, title, rect, obiee

OBIEE generates line bar chart and showing data labels as below

It is a partial code. I am looking for to add `tooltip` on each `rect` element from It is respective data labels shown and hide the data label shown on each bar.

Following things are challenging

1. How to add `<title><title>` in between `<rect>` eg. `<rect><title></title></rect>`
2. Need to pick dynamically pick it is respective data labels for title.

I am not much familiar with `JQuery` or `Javscript` and able to pick your solution. Looking for dynamic code

**line Bar Chart**

[image]

find the code :

```html
<svg viewBox="0 -1 583 169">
<g>
  <g>
    <rect fill="#ffffff" x="0" y="0" width="583" height="168" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="0" pointer-events="visiblePainted"></rect>
    <rect fill="none" x="50" y="7" width="523" height="76" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="0" pointer-events="visiblePainted" shape-rendering="crispEdges"></rect><text fill="#333333" x="93" y="113" font-family="Courier New" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" font-size="9" transform="rotate(315 115,109)" pointer-events="visiblePainted">31-Dec-15</text><text fill="#333333" x="224" y="113" font-family="Courier New"
      aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" font-size="9" transform="rotate(315 246,109)" pointer-events="visiblePainted">31-Dec-16</text><text fill="#333333" x="354.5" y="113" font-family="Courier New" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" font-size="9" transform="rotate(315 377,109)"
      pointer-events="visiblePainted">28-Feb-17</text><text fill="#333333" x="485.5" y="113" font-family="Courier New" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" font-size="9" transform="rotate(315 508,109)" pointer-events="visiblePainted">16-Apr-17</text>
    <text
      fill="#333333" x="39" y="86" font-family="tahoma, sans-serif" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" font-size="11" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" pointer-events="visiblePainted">0</text><text fill="#333333" x="18" y="73" font-family="tahoma, sans-serif" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" font-size="11" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" pointer-events="visiblePainted">4,000</text><text fill="#333333" x="18" y="61" font-family="tahoma, sans-serif"
        aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" font-size="11" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" pointer-events="visiblePainted">8,000</text><text fill="#333333" x="12" y="48" font-family="tahoma, sans-serif" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" font-size="11"
        transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" pointer-events="visiblePainted">12,000</text><text fill="#333333" x="12" y="36" font-family="tahoma, sans-serif" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" font-size="11" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" pointer-events="visiblePainted">16,000</text>
      <text
        fill="#333333" x="12" y="23" font-family="tahoma, sans-serif" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" font-size="11" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" pointer-events="visiblePainted">20,000</text><text fill="#333333" x="12" y="10" font-family="tahoma, sans-serif" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" font-size="11" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" pointer-events="visiblePainted">24,000</text>
        <line fill="none" x1="50" y1="83" x2="573"
          y2="83" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="0" pointer-events="visiblePainted" stroke="#9e9e9e" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" shape-rendering="crispEdges"></line>
        <line fill="none" x1="50" y1="83" x2="50" y2="7" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="0" pointer-events="visiblePainted" stroke="#9e9e9e" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" shape-rendering="crispEdges"></line>
        <rect fill="#2e87c1" x="66" y="66" width="49" height="17" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" pointer-events="visiblePainted" cursor="pointer"></rect>
        <rect fill="#7dc25b" x="115" y="39" width="49" height="44" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" pointer-events="visiblePainted" cursor="pointer"></rect>
        <rect fill="#2e87c1" x="197" y="81" width="49" height="2" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" pointer-events="visiblePainted" cursor="pointer"></rect>
        <rect fill="#7dc25b" x="246" y="76" width="49" height="7" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" pointer-events="visiblePainted" cursor="pointer"></rect>
        <rect fill="#2e87c1" x="328" y="67" width="49" height="16" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" pointer-events="visiblePainted" cursor="pointer"></rect>
        <rect fill="#7dc25b" x="377" y="33" width="49" height="50" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" pointer-events="visiblePainted" cursor="pointer"></rect>
        <rect fill="#2e87c1" x="459" y="67" width="49" height="16" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" pointer-events="visiblePainted" cursor="pointer"></rect>
        <rect fill="#7dc25b" x="508" y="33" width="49" height="50" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" pointer-events="visiblePainted" cursor="pointer"></rect>
        <polyline fill="none" points="115 23 246 74 377 17 508 17" aria-hidden="true" pointer-events="visiblePainted" stroke="#99ccff" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="3" stroke-linejoin="round" clip-path="url(#plotAreaClip_sawc_3x4$cp3)"></polyline>
        <ellipse fill="#99ccff" aria-hidden="true" cx="115" cy="23" rx="3" ry="3" fill-opacity="1" pointer-events="visiblePainted" cursor="pointer"></ellipse>
        <ellipse fill="#99ccff" aria-hidden="true" cx="246" cy="74" rx="3" ry="3" cursor="pointer" pointer-events="visiblePainted" fill-opacity="1"></ellipse>
        <ellipse fill="#99ccff" aria-hidden="true" cx="377" cy="17" rx="3" ry="3" cursor="pointer" pointer-events="visiblePainted" fill-opacity="1"></ellipse>
        <ellipse fill="#99ccff" aria-hidden="true" cx="508" cy="17" rx="3" ry="3" cursor="pointer" pointer-events="visiblePainted" fill-opacity="1"></ellipse><text fill="#3b3b3b" x="72.5" y="67" font-family="tahoma, sans-serif" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" font-size="11" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" pointer-events="visiblePainted" cursor="pointer">5,083.3</text><text fill="#3b3b3b"
          x="208" y="81" font-family="tahoma, sans-serif" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" font-size="11" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" pointer-events="visiblePainted" cursor="pointer">634.5</text><text fill="#3b3b3b" x="333.5" y="67" font-family="tahoma, sans-serif"
          aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" font-size="11" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" pointer-events="visiblePainted" cursor="pointer">5,047.0</text><text fill="#3b3b3b" x="464.5" y="67" font-family="tahoma, sans-serif" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1"
          font-size="11" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" pointer-events="visiblePainted" cursor="pointer">5,047.0</text><text fill="#3b3b3b" x="119" y="39" font-family="tahoma, sans-serif" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" font-size="11" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"
          pointer-events="visiblePainted" cursor="pointer">13,675.4</text><text fill="#3b3b3b" x="252.5" y="76" font-family="tahoma, sans-serif" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" font-size="11" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" pointer-events="visiblePainted"
          cursor="pointer">1,946.1</text><text fill="#3b3b3b" x="380" y="33" font-family="tahoma, sans-serif" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" font-size="11" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" pointer-events="visiblePainted" cursor="pointer">15,606.2</text>
        <text
          fill="#3b3b3b" x="511" y="33" font-family="tahoma, sans-serif" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" font-size="11" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" pointer-events="visiblePainted" cursor="pointer">15,606.2</text><text fill="#3b3b3b" x="98.5" y="23" font-family="tahoma, sans-serif" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" font-size="11" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" pointer-events="visiblePainted">18,759</text><text fill="#3b3b3b" x="232" y="74"
            font-family="tahoma, sans-serif" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" font-size="11" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" pointer-events="visiblePainted">2,581</text><text fill="#3b3b3b" x="360.5" y="17" font-family="tahoma, sans-serif" aria-hidden="true"
            fill-opacity="1" font-size="11" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" pointer-events="visiblePainted">20,653</text><text fill="#3b3b3b" x="491.5" y="17" font-family="tahoma, sans-serif" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" font-size="11" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"
            pointer-events="visiblePainted">20,653</text>
          <rect fill="none" x="98" y="149" width="387" height="13" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" pointer-events="visiblePainted" shape-rendering="crispEdges"></rect>
          <rect fill="#2e87c1" aria-hidden="true" x="102" y="151" width="10" height="10" fill-opacity="1" pointer-events="visiblePainted"></rect>
          <rect fill="#7dc25b" aria-hidden="true" x="228" y="151" width="10" height="10" fill-opacity="1" pointer-events="visiblePainted"></rect>
          <line fill="#7dc25b" x1="355" y1="156" x2="364" y2="156" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" pointer-events="visiblePainted" stroke="#99ccff" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="2"></line>
          <ellipse fill="#99ccff" aria-hidden="true" cx="360" cy="156" rx="3" ry="3" fill-opacity="1" pointer-events="visiblePainted"></ellipse><text fill="#333333" x="115" y="159" font-family="Arial" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" font-size="11" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" pointer-events="visiblePainted">Category1</text><text fill="#333333" x="242" y="159" font-family="Arial"
            aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" font-size="11" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" pointer-events="visiblePainted">Category2</text><text fill="#333333" x="368" y="159" font-family="Arial" aria-hidden="true" fill-opacity="1" font-size="11" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"
            pointer-events="visiblePainted">Overall Category</text></g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: It is going to be very tricky without extra information to tie the labels to their matching rectangle elements.  The rectangles start part way through the file in horizontal order. Then later in the file are all the blue labels, followed afterwards by all the green labels.  Without information (such as ids or element grouping) it is not feasible to manipulate an arbitrary graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following jQuery used to add tooltip to bar charts. Since text on bar is not in sequence, I followed add tooltip separately.  We don't have to really change standard code instead just a wrapper code(static view contains html) on top of existing chart.

This should  have mutation observer to avoid unneccessary addition when page refresh happens.

```js
//Adding tooltip for Green color rect

$.each(

$('svg g g > rect[fill="#2e87c1"]:nth-of-type(odd)') , function( key, value ) 
{ 

  var iter =  key;
  var titleforrect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","title")
  
  var objText = $('svg g g > text[fill="#3b3b3b"]');
  var szText = objText.length;
  var szTextSet = szText / 3;
  
  var datalabel = objText.slice(0,szText-szTextSet).eq(iter).text();
  
  //console.log(datalabel);
  
  titleforrect.textContent = datalabel
  
  value.append(titleforrect);
}
  
);

// Adding tooltip for Green color rect
$.each(

$('svg g g > rect[fill="#7dc25b"]:nth-of-type(even)') , function( key, value ) 
{ 

  var iter = $('svg g g > rect[fill="#7dc25b"]:nth-of-type(even)').length + key;
  var titleforrect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","title")
  
  var objText = $('svg g g > text[fill="#3b3b3b"]');
  var szText = objText.length;
  var szTextSet = szText / 3;
  
  var datalabel = objText.slice(0,szText-szTextSet).eq(iter).text();
  
  //console.log(datalabel);
  
  titleforrect.textContent = datalabel
  
  value.append(titleforrect);
}
  
);
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to go for non-custom visualization then really go for non-custom visualization.

Use JET or D3js or the likes but do not try to hack the existing charting engine.

Go custom or use standard. Don't mess up the standard. That's a really bad idea.